# Problems booting Windows in virtual machine with separate disks for boot and main partitions

Tags: windows, boot, backup, uefi, windows-11

I have restored a Windows 11 system from a partition-level backup of the main partition. The system boots, but only with manual intervention.

Initially, it enters a recovery screen (see upper image). From here, the only viable option is to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, after which it is possible  to acquire the firmware boot menu (see  image second from top), as a submenu of the EFI settings user interface, allowing selection of the item for booting Windows. After selecting this item, Windows boots correctly.

After restoring the Windows partition, I attempted installing the bootloader first through the automated repair from installation media, and then manual steps. The latter did add the needed UEFI files to the boot partition as well as to register the menu entry for Windows in the system boot menu. Both are of course  essential after recovering from a backup of just the Windows partition. However, normal boot remains elusive.

For reference, the target  platform is  a Qemu/KVM virtual machine on a x86 host. It was freshly provisioned with only default firmware settings preceding the data  restoration. It has three virtual disks, one containing the EFI boot partition and Windows reserved partition, a second containing the Windows main partition (the one restored from backup), and a third containing a   partition designated exclusively for a page file.

Analysis of the EFI boot entries from a non-Windows recovery environment confirms that the sole Windows boot entry is selected as the default (see image third from top).

To summarize, the boot procedure currently is the following:

1. *System initially enters Windows recovery environment.*
2. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter system firmware environment.
3. Select Windows as boot option from UEFI menu.
4. *Windows loads normally.*

Naturally, on a basic, properly-provisioned system,   the final  step would  be the first and only.   In principle, the original boot attempt should be simply a selection of the default boot item in the firmware, shown as the first entry on the list, and should not produce a different behavior from the manual selection. Yet, one case leads to the recovery environment, the other to successful boot.  How may I correct the discrepancy?

---

[image: Windows recovery screen]

[image: Firmware boot menu]

[image: Analysis of boot entries]

[image: Creation of boot record]

[image: Boot record analysis]

[image]

Comment: Can you try boot into the Linux environment from *cold* (fully shutdown; without attempting to boot Windows at all; by pressing `Esc` quickly right after starting qemu to get into the firmware setting), then check again with `efibootmgr` and see if `BootOrder` and `Boot000B` are *identical* to what you've shown? (Please check carefully.)

Comment: @TomYan, The design of the hypervisor interface makes it difficult to acquire a boot menu through the pre-emptive key combination. Generally, boot selection is determined by the VM provisioning in the hypervisor. I noticed that when I select the recovery environment as the sole boot device, the entries relating to the hard disks, including the Windows boot manager, are not listed by `efibootmgr`. The observation led me to discover that if select as *allowed* boot devices both the virtual disks containing the EFI partition as well as the one containing the Windows partition, boot is normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved.

Windows  has booted   successfully, directly after the system is started, only when both the virtual hard disks containing the EFI boot partition and the Windows data partition have been marked as potential boot devices in the virtualization hypervisor, Qemu.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR Simply change the boot order in UEFI > Boot to the NEW Windows bootloader manager. Currently you're booting an old and now wrong EFI entry because it points to a now non-existent OS which is the original installation.**

EFI entries aren't removed when the main OS partition is because they reside in the ESP (EFI System Partition). They can be left alone as long as the correct boot entry is selected in UEFI, typically in the Boot menu, or tools/commands can be used from within OSes to manage those entries (select a new boot order or remove entries) or often inside the UEFI settings.

DON'T confuse UEFI settings > Boot menu with the one-time boot menu / boot override menu (self-explanatory) you've been using to select the correct OS. You need to actually open UEFI settings and change the boot order there.

> I have tried an automated repair from installation media, and also manual steps to recreate the boot records. The latter did add the needed UEFI files to the boot partition as well as register the menu entry for Windows in the system boot menu.

Doing this does not change the old .efi files that worked for the original installation and are still selected by default. In UEFI settings > Boot you'll likely find 2 (two) "Windows bootloader manager" so simply select the other one.

This is very simple to understand as long as you understand UEFI and its boot process.

Comment: I believe I am not using an "old and wrong" EFI entry, because no such entry exists on the machine. The machine was provisioned as an empty VM. The only EFI entries that would have been added for an OS installation was the one added in the Windows recovery environment after Windows was restored to the target partition.

Comment: The EFI entry that boots successfully is also the one configured as the default boot entry through the firmware.

Comment: No, it certainly isn't. If you're seeing an "Windows bootloader manager" in the one-time boot menu, and that works but the default option doesn't, then you MUST have 2. That NOT being the case there wouldn't be any option by that name to select from in the on-time boot menu. The ONLY purpose of said menu is to override the default selection. Please check again. The behavior you describe is  well-known and works exactly as answered.

Comment: *Normally Windows updates its own EFI entry as the default in the firmware whenever it boots successfully.* NO, it DOESN'T. It does that often when installing feature updates - for your convenience, because such updates usually ask for several reboots - but NOT when simply booting. Millions of dual-boot configurations (e.g. Windows + Linux) would be "compromised" if that was the case and they obviously aren't.

Comment: I believe the default boot is simply resolved by whichever entry is the first viable one in the selected ordering. Please review the capture of the firmware boot menu, and notice only one entry related to Windows, the one appearing first. Are you suggesting that by default  booting would proceed from some boot entry other than this first in this list, and one not even appearing in the list

Comment: What you don't understand is the one you're booting that goes to recovery, from the firmware's POV, IS a valid entry. But it goes to recovery because it CAN'T find whatever system partition it's pointing to, and the reasons for that are mostly irrelevant. Now, please check again: Open UEFI settings > BOOT menu and likely "OS selection", press ENTER and select the **other Windows entry** as the first priority. After confirming it now boot correctly then please accept the answer.

Comment: As stated, only one entry related to Windows appears in the boot menu generated by the firmware. Please refer to the screen capture included in the original question. If you are able to help me resolve the actual issue I am experiencing on my system, I would appreciate your contribution.

Comment: (...) There you should find a "BOOT" menu and inside some "OS selection" setting or similar. If in doubt please read your user's manual. So, as answered, *This is very simple to understand as long as you understand UEFI and its boot process.* Unfortunately your last comment proved you aren't there yet.

Comment: My understanding is that the screen capture shows the list of boot items permanently registered in the nonvolatile storage of the EFI firmware. The captured screen is accessible as a submenu of the main screen of the user interface provided by the EFI firmware.

Comment: Please don't conjecture about what I understand or have done. You doing so has not led you to make any constructive contribution.